# Trying to run a simple GLSL shader program with LWJGL but this code isn't working

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I'm trying to run this simple GLSL shader code using LWJGL but the display remains black.
(The toFloatBuffer(float[] array) method is specified in the class and works).

```
try {
        Display.create();
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 600));
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    GL11.glViewport(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());


    //Using buffers
    //bufferStuff();
    //shaderStuff();
    System.out.println(GL11.glGetString(GL11.GL_VERSION) + "\n");

    String vertexShaderSource = 
        "#version 400 core                           \n" +
        "                                            \n" +
        "void main()                                 \n" +
        "{                                           \n" +
        "    gl_Position = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0); \n" +
        "}                                           \n";

    String fragmentShaderSource =
        "#version 400 core                            \n" +
        "                                             \n" +
        "out vec4 color;                              \n" +
        "                                             \n" +
        "void main()                                  \n" +
        "{                                            \n" +
        "    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); \n" +
        "}                                            \n";

    int vertexShader = GL20.glCreateShader(GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GL20.glShaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderSource);
    GL20.glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    System.out.println(GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, GL20.glGetShaderi(vertexShader, GL20.GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH)));

    int fragmentShader = GL20.glCreateShader(GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    GL20.glShaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderSource);
    GL20.glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    System.out.println(GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, GL20.glGetShaderi(fragmentShader, GL20.GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH)));

    int program = GL20.glCreateProgram();
    GL20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
    GL20.glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
    GL20.glLinkProgram(program);
    System.out.println(GL20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program, GL20.glGetProgrami(program, GL20.GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH)));

    GL20.glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    GL20.glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    int VAO = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    GL11.glPointSize(4);

    while(!Display.isCloseRequested())
    {
        GL30.glClearBuffer(GL11.GL_COLOR, 0, toFloatBuffer(new float[]{0, 0, 0, 1}));

        GL20.glUseProgram(program);

        GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_POINTS, 0, 3);

        Display.sync(60);
        Display.update();
    }
```

The output of the program is this

```
4.2.11733 Compatibility Profile Context

Vertex shader was successfully compiled to run on hardware.

Fragment shader was successfully compiled to run on hardware.

Vertex shader(s) linked, fragment shader(s) linked.
```

The shaders seem to have compiled and linked correctly and supported by my OpenGL version.
Any idea why I'm getting a black screen?

Comment: you would only get a single red point in the middle of the screen

Comment: I can't see where any actual geometry is put into your VAO...? Are you sure you are drawing any geometry? Do you see anything when not using shaders? Also: what is `out vec4 color` and why is it not written to nor bound to any output buffer? Many questions... could be anything including the red dot @ratchet mentioned.

Comment: @Thomas look at the vertex shader; there is no attribute input just a hardcoded set to 0,0,0,0 ... which would result in a divide by 0 during perspective divide.

Comment: @ratchetfreak I saw that. Nevertheless, the vertex shader has to actually be called, which would not be the case if no geometry was rendered, right? About the additional out vec4 ... i just checked, its actually allowed to declare superflous outputs, so thats indeed no problem.

Comment: @Thomas but the result has the w = 0 and the GPU will then pass 0/0, 0/0, 0/0, 1 to the fragment shader. What's the policy on that?

Comment: @ratchetfreak For that, the policy is "point at infinity"-> outside clip space -> remove during clipping. You are right, this is an error. Anyhow, you also MUST draw s.th. to even get to this clipping ;)

Answer (score 3):

In your vertex shader the output is *always* `vec4(0, 0, 0, 0)` this always lies outside the clip space. Because after the vertex shader the GPU will divide all components with the 4th one if that is 0 then the point lies outside the clip space by default.

As that is the only possible output of the vertex shader that shader will never draw anything on screen. If you replace it with `vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)` then you would get a single red dot in the center of the screen.

Comment: Ah I missed that part. I'm just testing out shader writing and compilation without passing any data to it for now so I'm specifying the vertices and colors inside the shader itself.

Comment: I changed it to vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0). Same result. Black screen.

Answer (score 2):

Your fragment shader targets `#version 400` and you have explicitly told it that you want to restrict yourself to `core` (which is the default profile, by the way).

`gl_FragColor` is not a valid GL built-in in ***core*** GLSL. You need to write your shader using `#version 400 compatibility` if you want to write anything to `gl_FragColor`.

#### You have two options here:

1. Re-write your shader targeting `#version 400 compatibility`

   - I doubt this is what you want, because you already went ahead and declared a variable: `out vec4 color`
2. Output to `color` instead of `gl_FragColor`

I suspect you want option **#2**. Though in no circumstances should you have both a user-declared `out` variable in your fragment shader and write to `gl_FragColor`, that is invalid.

---

> #### [OpenGL Shading Language 4.00.9 Specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.00.9.clean.pdf#page=93)  -  7 Built-in Variables  -  p. 87
>
> > ***Deprecated:*** Writing to `gl_FragColor` specifies the fragment color that will be used by the subsequent fixed functionality pipeline. If subsequent fixed functionality consumes fragment color and an execution of the fragment shader executable does not write a value to `gl_FragColor` then the fragment color consumed is undefined.

#### Later versions of the specification make this a lot clearer:

> #### [OpenGL Shading Language 4.20.11 Specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.20.11.clean.pdf#page=112)  -  7 Built-in Variables  -  p. 106
>
> > The following fragment output variables are available in a fragment shader when using the ***compatibility*** profile:
> >
> > ```
> >  out vec4 gl_FragColor;
> >  out vec4 gl_FragData[gl_MaxDrawBuffers];
> > ```

Comment: isn't there also the option of redeclaring gl_FragColor?

Comment: @ratchetfreak: For `gl_FragColor`? Not that I'm aware of - only `gl_FragDepth` (when conservative depth was added) and `gl_FragCoord` (to specify the fragment center convention). There is a gray area I stumbled across though:  _"... if user declared output variables are in use (statically assigned to), then the built-in variables `gl_FragColor` and `gl_FragData` may not be assigned to. These incorrect usages all generate compile time
errors."_ Nothing's ever explicitly assigned to `color` in this case, but there really shouldn't be user-defined `out` variables in a shader using `gl_FragColor`.

Comment: (_even in a compatibility shader_).